# ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'innodb_write_io_threads' is a read only variable

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

I want to change "innodb_write_io_threads=4" and "innodb_read_io_threads=4" to

"innodb_write_io_threads=64"
"innodb_read_io_threads=64"

But it gives error when i try to "SET GLOBAL innodb_write_io_threads = 64;

Also, i added in my.cnf file after that i restart mysqld, but nothing changed.

I didn't find any solution. I searched on google and didn't find any solution. I need help. Thanks.

Comment: What section you put it in matters significantly.

Comment: /etc/mysql/my.cnf i added:

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/

[mysqld]
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
innodb_write_io_threads = 64
@tadman

Comment: Are you sure you need to change the number of io threads? I have seldom seen a case that needed it. Run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` and scroll to the line like `Pending normal aio reads: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0]` and observe the numbers are 0 most of the time. That means you have IO threads that are not overly committed, and you don't need to increase the number of IO threads. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-performance-multiple_io_threads.html

Comment: Pages read 3003126, created 5, written 574
213.97 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.02 writes/s

It reads a lot of time.  %CPU %MEM 518.1  1.2 mysqld

Comment: Your mysqld is only using 1.2% of the system RAM? Sounds like you could increase `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and probably reduce the IO rate a lot by caching more data & indexes.

Comment: show variables like 'innodb_buffer_pool_size';
+-------------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name           | Value     |
+-------------------------+-----------+
| innodb_buffer_pool_size | 134217728

No i didn't increase it.

Comment: Change it!  Set it (in my.cnf or the include file) to about 70% of RAM.  Then restart.  Meanwhile, what version of MySQL are you using?